# c# send audio from file by microphone

Tags: c#, audio, send, microphone

is there a way to send recorded music from a file to my microphone to send it over voip? i mean like i say hello, i record hello and when i open the program it says hello with skype or something.
i cant explain it better by my english :P but i hope somebody got an solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather unclear, but in the interest of providing at least some guidance, here is a list of open source VOIP software that may help you on your way:
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Open+Source+VOIP+Software

That page lists at least one C# implementation.